# Why does the PyQt Window crash whenever my function is ran

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

My code looks like this

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 600, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle("HBCheat")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Reaction Cheat")
        self.label.move(10, 0)

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("Toggle: off")
        self.b1.move(10, 35)
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.reaction_cheat)
    
    def click(self,x,y): 
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
        time.sleep(0.01) 
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    
    def reaction_cheat(self):
        self.b1.setText("Toggle: on")
        while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            try:
                if pyautogui.pixel(1298, 415)[1] == 219:
                    self.click(1298, 415)
            except:
                continue
        self.b1.setText("Toggle: off")
```

Whenever I click on button "b1" it should run the function reaction_cheat. Which it does. But the problem is that the text for the button does not change and the window crashes. If I press the button it still works as intended but the button text does not change. And if I were to comment out the "while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):" loop. It would change the buttons text and the function would end.

So Why is it that the the text for b1 doesn't change and the window crashes.

Also when I press q it doesn't stop the window from crashes. But it still stops the loop and stops the function from running.

Comment: The button text doesnt change as it's getting the update for the window is getting blocked by the while loop, after the line "self.b1.setText("Toggle: on")" add QApplication.processEvents(), that should solve the issue for the button text not updating.

It may be worth creating a separate QThread or process to handle the mouse_event to try and avoid blocking the GUI if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because the logic that checks if the key <kbd>q</kbd> is pressed or does not consume a lot of time blocking the eventloop.

A possible solution is to use threads but another solution is to use the add_hotkey function that allows to use a callback avoiding the use of while loops. You should also avoid using time.sleep(). In this case the logic is that if the button is pressed then the task of verifying the pixel will be executed every T seconds until the user presses the <kbd>q</kbd> key.

```py
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QPushButton

import pyautogui
import keyboard

import win32api
import win32con


class KeyBoardHelper(QObject):
    pressed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, hotkey="", parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._hotkey = hotkey

    @property
    def hotkey(self):
        return self._hotkey

    @hotkey.setter
    def hotkey(self, hotkey):
        self.stop()
        self._hotkey = hotkey

    def start(self):
        keyboard.add_hotkey(self.hotkey, self._callback)

    def stop(self):
        try:
            keyboard.remove_hotkey(self._callback)
        except KeyError:
            pass

    def _callback(self):
        self.pressed.emit()


class MouseHelper:
    def click(self, x, y):
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
        self._press()

    def _press(self):
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
        QTimer.singleShot(10, self._release)

    def _release(self):
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 600, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle("HBCheat")
        self.initUI()

        self.keyboard_helper.pressed.connect(self.handle_keyboard_pressed)
        self.keyboard_helper.hotkey = "q"

        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.verify_pixel)

    @cached_property
    def keyboard_helper(self):
        return KeyBoardHelper()

    @cached_property
    def mouse_helper(self):
        return MouseHelper()

    @cached_property
    def timer(self):
        return QTimer(interval=10)

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Reaction Cheat")
        self.label.move(10, 0)

        self.b1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("Toggle: off")
        self.b1.move(10, 35)
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.reaction_cheat)

    def click(self, x, y):
        print("X")
        """"
        """

    def reaction_cheat(self):
        self.b1.setText("Toggle: on")
        self.keyboard_helper.start()
        self.timer.start()

    def handle_keyboard_pressed(self):
        self.keyboard_helper.stop()
        self.timer.start()
        self.b1.setText("Toggle: off")

    def verify_pixel(self):
        try:
            if pyautogui.pixel(1298, 415)[1] == 219:
                self.mouse_helper.click(1298, 415)
        except:
            pass


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```